# grep and output whole word

Tags: grep

I have a long, long log file of SQL commands, and I'm interesting in grep'ing just the name of the tables. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_02323
SELECT * FROM table_231
SELECT * FROM table_1
```

I want to grep so that the result returns

```
table_02323
table_231
table_1
```

The closest thing I've gotten is `grep -o 'table.....' this.log` but obviously the suffix will have different lengths. Is there a regex expression to output without being constrained by a fix length as is the case w/ using periods?

Comment: I assume you only want table names from "select" statements?? And will the table name always be on the same line as the select? Do all the table names start with "table_"?

Comment: `egrep -io '\<from[ ]+[^ ]+' | sort -u`, then you can use `sed` or `grep` again to remove the `FROM`s.  But split lines would fool this, you'd need a real SQL parser to get around that.

Answer (score 4):

This will match "table_" following by 0 or more ASCII digits:

```
grep -o 'table_[0-9]*' this.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU `grep` like below:

```
grep -oiP 'FROM\s*\K\w+' infile
```

Non-GNU:

```
grep -ioP 'FROM[ ]*\K[A-Z_0-9]+' infile
```

This will ensure you are just getting table name.

Test:

```
grep -ioP 'FROM\s*\K\w+' <<<"SELECT * FROM table_02323 where 1=1"
table_02323
```

Comment: Yes, updated answer

Answer (score 0):

From `man grep`:

> ```
> Repetition
>        A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition operators:
>        ...
>        *      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
> ```

So you want to use something like

```
$ grep -o 'table\w*'
```

where `\w` is any non-whitespace character, repeated zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach, using lookbehind:

```
$ grep -P -o -e '(?<=^SELECT \* FROM )(.*$)' < 'file'
table_02323
table_231
table_1
```